# Python join three strings from different lines from log file into one line

Tags: python, logparser

I need to concatenate three different strings from different lines into one line.
My log file looks like this:

```
2020-07-03 15:21:58,962 ERROR [AIF]: Line: 6, Error: No such member
2020-07-03 15:21:58,962 ERROR [AIF]: Actual;2020;Jun;YTD;EWHG;<Entity Currency>;A1399;401700;[None];[None];[None];[None];-7537030.790000000000
2020-07-03 15:21:58,962 ERROR [AIF]: >>>>>>401700
2020-07-03 15:21:58,962 ERROR [AIF]: 
2020-07-03 15:21:58,962 ERROR [AIF]: Line: 7, Error: The member of the Account dimension is not base level.
2020-07-03 15:21:58,962 ERROR [AIF]: Actual;2020;Jun;YTD;EWRA;<Entity Currency>;A1399;[ICP None];[None];[None];[None];[None];44984167.990000000000
2020-07-03 15:21:58,962 ERROR [AIF]: >>>>>>A1399
2020-07-03 15:21:58,962 ERROR [AIF]: 
2020-07-03 15:21:58,962 ERROR [AIF]: Line: 15, Error: The member of the Account dimension is not base level.
2020-07-03 15:21:58,962 ERROR [AIF]: Actual;2020;Jun;YTD;EWHG;<Entity Currency>;A2090;[ICP None];[None];[None];[None];[None];0.270000000000
2020-07-03 15:21:58,962 ERROR [AIF]: >>>>>>A2090
```

Error:

```
Line: 6, Error: No such member | >>>>>>401700 | Actual;2020;Jun;YTD;EWHG;<Entity Currency>;A1399;401700;[None];[None];[None];[None];-7537030.790000000000
```

Below is my code, which is writing in different lines:

```
def main():
    fo = open("C:\\Users\\yannis\\py_script\\FMC_1198.log", "r", encoding="ISO-8859-1")
    ofile = open("C:\\Users\\yannis\\py_script\\out_log.txt",'a', newline='')

    vinter = ""
    vline = ""
    vmember = ""

    f1 = fo.readlines()
    for x in f1:

        res = x.partition('Line:')[2]
        if len(res) > 0:
            vline = res
            continue
        res = x.partition('>>>>>>')[2]
        if len(res) > 0:
            vmember = res
            continue
        res = x.partition('Actual;')[2]
        if len(res) > 0:
            vinter = res
            continue

        linha = vinter + vline + vmember
        if len(linha) > 0:
            print(linha)
            ofile.write(linha)
            continue


    fo.close()
    ofile.close()
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because there are `\n` at the end of the strings, you should write a helper function

```py
def trimNewlines(st):
  return st.replace("\n")
```

Or

```py
def trimNewlines(st):
  return st.rstrip("\n")
```

If you only want to remove newlines on the right of the strings and not from the middle or left

Comment: Thank you so much! However in my out file it writes in only one line, while in the console it prints correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: I do actually, the newlines in the console are there because print appends newlines, the write function you are calling does not, maybe use `ofile.write(linha + "\n")`

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of something like the following:

```
new_log = str()

with open("old_log.txt", 'r') as input_file:
    lines = [line[37:-1] for line in input_file.readlines()]
    lines = [l for (i,l) in enumerate(lines) if i%4!=3]

    remastered = list()
    i = 0
    while i + 2 < len(lines):
        remastered.append(f"{lines[i]} | {lines[i+2]} | {lines[i+1]}")
        i += 3

    new_log = '\n'.join(remastered)

with open("new_log.txt", 'a') as input_file:
    input_file.write(new_log+'\n')
```

Comment: Thank you. However its not working, I get index out of range;

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/yannis/py_script/t2.py", line 10, in <module>
    remastered.append(f"{lines[i]} | {lines[i+2]} | {lines[i+1]}")
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Do you perform the program while you are writing the logs? If so, I've changed the check. Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

try this, using `zip` + `list splicing`

```
# pre-processing, to remove un-wanted lines & starting character's
lines = []

for l in fo.readlines():
    _, y = l.split("[AIF]:")
    if y.strip():
        lines.append(y)

with open("test.txt", 'w') as f:
    # list splicing with zip, job done..
    lines = [f"{a} | {b} | {c}\n"
             for a, b, c in zip(lines[0::3], lines[2::3], lines[1::3])]
    
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'text' is not defined